# An empty super class?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to have an observable list that can list TableObjects (Self made class). I will send this observable list to a TableView object. My question: is there any point in having an empty super class?

I'm going to create three different tables, which shows three different types of objects. My plan is to create these types from the TableObjects, meaning that I will create subclasses that extends TableObject. So TableObjectA, B and C will have String values like for example name or type.

I could actually just drop the super TableObject super class, but isn't it in my interest for design specific reasons? I've actually learned little about software design, and how to design a software that will be future development friendly from the courses I've been taking.

Comment: Do you plan on having any sibling classes to the subclass? If not, it might not be worth it. If so, it is.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need 3 different TableObject classes? It seems like a single TableObject class would work, whether you template it or have it accept a super type common to A,B,and C

Comment: The different sub classes don't have the same values that I want to display in the table, meaning that each TableObject has different things I want to show. Say for example that A is for  a CarTable and B is for a BoatTable.

Comment: If you design the table so that it is basically a list of lists, you can put whatever you want in it.  It's both versatile and scalable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just describe the [Marker interface pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern) and, in your case, it should not be an empty superclass but an interface.

Answer (score 1):

If your super-class represents a common behavior you can have it in place. If you want all your classes to incorporate any specific behavior you can have an interface in place. But, if you want to have a super-class only for the sake of clubbing few child classes together or for any reason alike, I would recommend to adhere to appropriate class naming convention to do so and NOT to have super-class.